# Generic extension method for NullIf<T>() supporting nullable and non-nullable value types

Tags: c#, generics, null, extension-methods

I would like a simple, modestly efficient `NullIf()` generic extension for nullable and non-nullable value types including enums. The trickiness seems to be with equality testing in generics.

Any issues with this working implementation?

```
/// <summary>
/// Return null if the value is equal to the argument.  Applies to value types including enums.
/// </summary>
public static T? NullIf<T>(this T value, T equalsThis) 
    where T : struct, IComparable // values types (including enum)
{
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, equalsThis) == 0
        ? (T?)null
        : value;
}

/// <summary>
/// Return null if the value is null or the value is equal to the argument.
/// Applies to value types including enums.
/// </summary>
public static T? NullIf<T>(this T? value, T equalsThis) 
    where T : struct, IComparable  // values types (including enum)
{
    return !value.HasValue
        ? (T?)null
        : value.Value.NullIf(equalsThis);
}
```

Test cases:

```
int i = 32;
int? i2 = i.NullIf(32); // null
int? i3 = i.NullIf(50); // 32

System.IO.FileAccess fa = System.IO.FileAccess.Read;
System.IO.FileAccess? fa2 = fa.NullIf(System.IO.FileAccess.Read);       // null
System.IO.FileAccess? fa3 = fa.NullIf(System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite);  // Read
```

References: [`Comparer<T>.Default`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19895216/538763)

Comment: mhmm... when I'm looking at the test cases this doesn't seem to be very useful. What is the real purpose of these exctensions? ;-]

Comment: Its a standard DB function: NullIf() in Sql Server. Google turns up some examples. It more for string processing although i wanted a typesafe enum version.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I've been using it myself in sql queries many times where it's quite useful - I totaly missed that one, lol, sorry ;-) I cannot however think of any example where I would need it in C#. Usually you don't want `null`s. But I guess you have such a case, haven't you?

Comment: I find this _function_ always a little bit counter-intuitive as actually it should be called _Null-If-Equal_. With this name I think there would be less confusion about its purpose or even better _First-Or-Null-If-Equal_.

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 4 → 3.

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of observations:

1. Neither [`Comparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47(v=vs.110).aspx) nor [`IComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) pose any type restrictions on `T`. So I don't see any need for imposing an `IComparable` restriction in the implementation.

   The other option would be to keep the `IComparable` restriction and make actually use of that interface (i.e. `return value.CompareTo(equalsThis) == 0`)
2. `IComparable` is the wrong abstraction to use. `IComparable` is meant for objects to provide a sort order as it has the concept of smaller, equal and greater. For your purposes you simply want to test for equality - so you should use [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`EqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

**Update**:

Turns out that enums generally don't implement `IEquatable<T>`. The best option in that case would probably be to allow the user to optionally pass in an `IEqualityComparer<T>` defaulting to `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` and again not impose any additional type restrictions.

Comment: The link referenced at the end of question states that the Comparer<T>.Default.Compare() supports IComparable<T> types (yes, not imposed on T, just optional).  I verified this to be true in the .NET source code.  I plan to convert it over to use EqualityComparer<T> anyway.

Comment: Unlike IComparable, enums don't seem to support IEquatable<T> (compile error "there is no boxing conversion") and there is no non-generic IEquatable so I dropped the constraint.

Comment: @crokusek: answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Even though it turned out that `NullIf` is inspired by a similar SQL function [`NULLIF`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql) I think the C# *edition* should be calles *FirstOrNullIfEqual*. I always fould the SQL one a little bit counter-intuitive and incomplete becasue every time I see it I'm automatically asking myself *null-if what?*

As far as the API is concered I think one more overload allowing to specify a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` would be useful in many cases:

```
public static T? NullIf<T>(this T value, T equalsThis, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
```